# This code must be printing an array of index positions but its not printing anything

Tags: c++

This is the complete question:-
All Indices Of Array

1. You are given a number n, representing the count of elements.
2. You are given n numbers.
3. You are given a number x.
4. You are required to find the all indices at which x occurs in array a.
5. Return an array of appropriate size which contains all indices at which x occurs in array a.

Sample Input
6
15
11
40
4
4
9

Sample Output
3
4

This is my code:-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int* allIndices(int arr[],int n,int x,int idx,int* fsf){
    if(idx==n){
        int *q=new int[*fsf];
        return q;
    }
    if(arr[idx]==x){
        
        int* iarr=allIndices(arr,n,x,idx+1,fsf+1);
        iarr[*fsf]=idx;
        return iarr;
        
    }
    else{
        int* iarr=allIndices(arr,n,x,idx+1,fsf);
        return iarr;
    }
}
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int *p = new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>p[i];
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    int k=0;
    int *y=allIndices(p,n,x,0,&k);
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
        cout<<y[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

This code must be printing an array of index positions but its not printing anything ....
please help!

Comment: Is there any specific problem you faced? Please [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask good questions.

Comment: You pass an integer as a pointer (&k -> fsf), but then you PASS THE 'POINTER + 1'! This can't work. You expect the value of k to change, but *fsf is never changed. Wouldn't it be simpler to pass fsf as reference instead of pointer?

Comment: Also, this may be an exercise and your teacher may not agree, but working with std::vector is much simpler than working with dynamic arrays. It doesn't matter in small exercises, but it is a bad habit of creating memory leaks by not deleting memory allocated with new.

Answer (score 0):

This does the job quite fine. You might have overcomplicated it a bit.

```
  #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int* alLIndices(int arr[], int n, int x){
    int *y = new int[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(arr[i] == x){
            y[i] = i;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Number "<<x<<" occurs at indices: "<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<y[i]<<endl;
    }
}


int main() {

    int n;
    cout<<"Enter n: ";
    cin>>n;
    int *p = new int[n];
    cout<<"Enter an array of numbers: "<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cin>>p[i];
    int x;
    cout<<"Enter x: ";
    cin>>x;

    alLIndices(p, n, x);

    return 0;
}
```

You just go through the array and see which element of it is equal to the x that you are searching for. If there is any, then you put the index of that element in a new array which you allocated beforehand. Finally, you print out the array containing those indices.

Comment: Hello @A_Mel, actually i was learning recusion so i wanted a recursive solution only to my problem, also i have found a solution to this but there are still some doubts which i have for this particular code .

Comment: I see. There is a great video on recursion on youtube. It might just help you. External links are not allowed, seems like. Just search "5 Simple Steps for Solving Any Recursive Problem"